# Mysql double left outer join with count

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I have the following DB structure:

- Song (ID, ...)
- Review (SongID, Accept)

I want to view all songs and count how many accepts and how many declines a song has.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT(ra.ID) as Accepts, COUNT(rd.ID) as Declines 
FROM song s
LEFT OUTER JOIN review ra ON s.ID = ra.SongID AND ra.Accept = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN review rd ON s.ID = rd.SongID AND rd.Accept = 0
GROUP BY s.ID
```

This doesn't yield the correct result. I have a song with 3 accepts and 1 decline, the query outputs 3 accepts and 3 declines. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with juergen's solution is that if a song has no review then `r.accept` will be `null`. When you compare a `null` value using `=` you get `null` as a result. (You should use `IS` in order to compare `null` values). Then, if you `SUM` (add) `null` values then you get a `null` value again.

So, you should make sure that when a song has no review, it will return `0` instead of `null`:

```
SELECT s.ID, 
       COALESCE(SUM(r.Accept = 1), 0) as Accepts, 
       COALESCE(SUM(r.Accept = 0), 0) as Declines 
FROM song s
LEFT OUTER JOIN review r ON s.ID = r.SongID
GROUP BY s.ID
```

`COALESCE` will take the first non-`null` argument from the list, so if the `SUM` is null then a `0` will be put in its place.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.ID, 
       SUM(r.Accept = 1) as Accepts, 
       SUM(r.Accept = 0) as Declines 
FROM song s
LEFT OUTER JOIN review r ON s.ID = r.SongID
GROUP BY s.ID
```

Comment: Wow, TIL. Didn't know you could do that.